# Is "xmlns:log4j" a required attribute of the <log4j:configuration> tag?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j

I see a bunch of sample log4j configurations that contain `xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"` in the `<log4j:configuration>` tag, is this attribute required? What does having this attribute in my configuration do for me?

Example:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="infoLogsFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="MyApplication.log"/>     
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root> 
        <priority value ="DEBUG" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="infoLogsFile"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Could I do this instead?

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="infoLogsFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="MyApplication.log"/>     
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root> 
        <priority value ="DEBUG" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="infoLogsFile"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute specifies that elements prepended with `log4j` are defined by the schema referenced by that URL. Log4J does not actually perform schema validation before attempting to parse the configuration file, so it is not actually required.